# how to use inputFormatters and limit the characters of Textformfield with listener

Tags: flutter, dart, listener, flutter-textformfield

I am using custom textFormField and custom keyboard's.

So In my custom TextFormField I want to set the maxlength to 16 and for every 4 characters I want to show some space (like our card Number).

I know how to use maxlength and inputFormatters to TextFormField but here I have to use listener for custom TextFormField.

```
controllerListener() {
    widget.controller.addListener(() {
 if (widget.type == KeyBoardType.CardNumberkeyBoard) {
         regexValidationCardNumber(controller: widget.controller,length: 16);
      }
}


regexValidationCardNumber({TextEditingController? controller, int? length}) {
  if(controller  != null && controller!.text.length > length!){
    print("User trying to add more characters");
   // maxlength 6
  //inputFormatters
  }
}


class CardNumberFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue previousValue,
      TextEditingValue nextValue,
      ) {
    var inputText = nextValue.text;

    if (nextValue.selection.baseOffset == 0) {
      return nextValue;
    }

    var bufferString =  StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < inputText.length; i++) {
      bufferString.write(inputText[i]);
      var nonZeroIndexValue = i + 1;
      if (nonZeroIndexValue % 4 == 0 && nonZeroIndexValue != inputText.length) {
        bufferString.write(' ');
      }
    }

    var string = bufferString.toString();
    return nextValue.copyWith(
      text: string,
      selection:  TextSelection.collapsed(
        offset: string.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

page:

```
SizedBox(
                        width: width,
                        child: CommonTextFormField().textFormField(
                          controller: _preAuthProvider.cardNumberController,
                          hintText:
                          AppLocalizations.of(context)!.cardNumber,
                          isCenter: false,
                         // isReadOnly: true,
                          suffixIcon: const Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                            child: Icon(Icons.credit_card),
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            _preAuthProvider.showBottomKeyBoard(
                             context,
                              keyBoardType: KeyBoardType.CardNumberkeyBoard,
                              controller: _preAuthProvider.cardNumberController,
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),


class CommonTextFormField {
  Widget textFormField({
    FieldType? type,
    Widget? icon,
    Widget? prefixIcon,
    Widget? suffixIcon,
    String? Function(String?)? validator,
    TextStyle? style,
    void Function()? onTap,
    String? hintText,
    String? labelText,
    TextEditingController? controller,
    String? initialValue,
    double? contentPaddingVertical,
    double? contentPaddingHorizontal,
    Color? lineColor,
    Function(String)? onChanged,
    Function(String)? onFieldSubmitted,
    bool hide = false,
    bool isCenter = true,
    bool isReadOnly = false,
    bool isEnd = false,
    bool enabled = true,
    bool isMultiLine = false,
    bool isCustomKeyBoard = false,
    bool isBorderEnable = true,
    bool isHintStyle = false,
    bool isForSearch = true,
  }) {
    return TextFormField(
      enabled: enabled,
      readOnly: isReadOnly,
      textInputAction: isForSearch ? TextInputAction.search : null,
      controller: controller,
     textAlign: type == FieldType.numericField ? TextAlign.end : isCenter ? TextAlign.center : isEnd ? TextAlign.justify
         : TextAlign.start,
     /* textAlign: isCenter
          ? TextAlign.center
          : isEnd
              ? TextAlign.justify
              : TextAlign.start,*/
      style: style,
      onFieldSubmitted: onFieldSubmitted,
      onChanged: onChanged,
      onTap: onTap,
      cursorWidth: 0,
      cursorHeight: 0,
      validator: validator,
      obscureText: hide,
      inputFormatters: [
        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
        CardNumberFormatter(),
      ],
      maxLength: 8,
      minLines: (type == FieldType.notesLine && isMultiLine ) ? 3 :null,
      maxLines: (type == FieldType.notesLine && isMultiLine ) ? 5 : 1,
      //minLines: isMultiLine ? 3 : null,
      //maxLines: isMultiLine ? 5 : 1,
      keyboardType: isMultiLine
          ? TextInputType.multiline
          : isCustomKeyBoard
              ? TextInputType.none
              : TextInputType.text,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        counterText: "",
        prefixIcon: type == FieldType.numericField
            ? const Padding(
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 10),
                child: Text("\$"),
              )
            : null,
        /*prefixIcon: icon != null
              ? Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15,horizontal: 10),
                  child: icon,
                )
              : null,*/
        suffixIcon: suffixIcon,
        isDense: true,
        labelText: (type == FieldType.labelField || type == FieldType.notesLine || type == FieldType.numericField
        ) ? labelText:null,
        //labelText: labelText,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: contentPaddingHorizontal ?? 0,
            vertical: contentPaddingVertical ?? 15),
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(),

        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: isBorderEnable
                    ? lineColor ?? Colors.white
                    : Colors.transparent)),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: isBorderEnable
                    ? lineColor ?? Colors.white
                    : Colors.transparent)),
        disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: isBorderEnable
                    ? lineColor ?? Colors.white
                    : Colors.transparent)),
        hintText: hintText,
        labelStyle: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        hintStyle: isHintStyle ? TextStyle(color: Colors.white) : TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5)),
        floatingLabelAlignment: FloatingLabelAlignment.start,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

controller:

```
  /// showBottomKeyBoard(context, { controller }) => show bottom keyBoard
  showBottomKeyBoard(
    BuildContext context, {
    TextEditingController? controller,
    KeyBoardType keyBoardType = KeyBoardType.DOUBLEZERO,
  }) {
    showKeyBoard(context,
        controller: controller!,
        backGroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
        buttonSize: 90,
        keyBoardType: keyBoardType);
  }
```

But I want this with listener.

Comment: How about including spaces on `maxLength: 16 + 3,`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh yes we have include that too

Comment: I am not getting any error if I’ve tested this correctly, Can you include full widget [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh with my custom textformfield widget maxlength and inputformatters are not working. I tested with fluter textformfiled and it is working fine but I have to do listener. I am using custom keyboard

Comment: Sorry, can't test until we are  aware of  your custom textformFiled `CommonTextFormField`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh added custom widget